# Exceljs append row

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx, appendfile

I wrote this code so I can save some info in excel file but it runs multiple time for every user and for some reason it doesn't append a new row but it removes old one and writes a new one. Anyone can help?

```
        // A new Excel Work Book
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

        // Create a sheet
        var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Sheet1");


        // Add rows in the above header
        sheet.addRow({
          user_id: info.id,
          user_tag: username,
          followed_by: inform.username,
          followers: info.edge_followed_by.count,
          followings: info.edge_follow.count,
          biography: info.biography,
          category: info.business_category_name,
          external_url: info.external_url,
          external_lynx_url: info.external_url_linkshimmed,
          is_verified: info.is_verified,
        });

        // Save Excel on Hard Disk
        workbook.xlsx.writeFile("business_accounts.xlsx").then(function () {
          // Success Message
          alert("User Saved");
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// A new Excel Work Book
        var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

        // Create a sheet
        var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Sheet1");

        for (user of users) {
        // Add rows in the above header
        sheet.addRow({
              user_id: info.id,
              user_tag: username,
              followed_by: inform.username,
              followers: info.edge_followed_by.count,
              followings: info.edge_follow.count,
              biography: info.biography,
              category: info.business_category_name,
              external_url: info.external_url,
              external_lynx_url: info.external_url_linkshimmed,
              is_verified: info.is_verified,
            });
        }

        // Save Excel on Hard Disk
        workbook.xlsx.writeFile("business_accounts.xlsx").then(function () {
          // Success Message
          alert("User Saved");
        });
```

you only need one excel file for all the users so only the addrow function need to be repeated. make sure you create and write only once.